# How to divide query 1 month to day in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

hay, assume i have query like this :

```
select * from product
```

and output like this:

```
id    name        date
1     telephone   2021-01-02
2     Handphone   2021-01-03
3     laptop      2021-01-04
```

and i will show every day in one month, example

```
   id    name        date
        1   telephone   2021-01-02
        2.  telephone   2021-01-03
        3.  telephone   2021-01-04
        4   telephone   2021-01-05
        5.  telephone   2021-01-06
        6.  telephone   2021-01-07
```

how to use query sql to output like above ?

Comment: Why do you only have "telephone" in the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate the data that you specify:

```
select row_number() over (order by dte) as id,
       'telephone' as name,
       gs.dte
from generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-31'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte);
```

Note that the `product` table is not being used.  It is not clear what that has to do with the result set.